# Disallow Facebook api from adding email to DB if one is already set

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I have a login system that allows for a user to signup or login using Facebook's api.

I've added some code to check if an email matching the Facebook email exist, and if so, add the Facebook id to that row in the database.

I also have an option in my account settings that allows a user to change their email address.

The problem i have is that if a user changes their email address after obtaining a Facebook id, the next time a user logs out then back in to my site, their email gets updated to the email on their Facebook account.

I still want to allow User::createOrUpdateGraphNode($facebook_user) to add an email to my database only if an email doesn't exist, hence for a new user.

But not if an email already exist. so that if a user does change their email, logging in with Facebook won't affect it.

I know i could remove from

```
protected static 

    $graph_node_field_aliases = [
            'id' => 'facebook_id',
            // 'name' => 'name',
            //'email' => 'email',
        ];
```

but then it won't add the email in my db when a new user signs up.

everything is going on in this function: `createOrUpdateGraphNode($facebook_user)`
so i'm not sure how to go about maybe adding an if something like this for example :

```
if($user->facebook_id == facebook_id && $user->email) { 
  do something 
}
```

I'm using sammyklaravel/facebooksdk https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

the Facebook callback looks like this:

```
function facebookCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb) {
    // Obtain an access token.
try {
    $token = $fb->getAccessTokenFromRedirect();
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    dd($e->getMessage());
}

// Access token will be null if the user denied the request
// or if someone just hit this URL outside of the OAuth flow.
if (! $token) {
    // Get the redirect helper
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    if (! $helper->getError()) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }

    // User denied the request
    dd(
        $helper->getError(),
        $helper->getErrorCode(),
        $helper->getErrorReason(),
        $helper->getErrorDescription()
    );
}

if (! $token->isLongLived()) {
    // OAuth 2.0 client handler
    $oauth_client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Extend the access token.
    try {
        $token = $oauth_client->getLongLivedAccessToken($token);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
}

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);

// Save for later
Session::put('fb_user_access_token', (string) $token);

// Get basic info on the user from Facebook.
try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email');
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    dd($e->getMessage());
}

// Convert the response to a `Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphUser` collection
$facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();
// dd($facebook_user['email'] );


// Create the user if it does not exist or update the existing entry.
// This will only work if you've added the SyncableGraphNodeTrait to your User model.
$user = User::where('email', $facebook_user['email'])->first();

if(isset($user)) {
    // // Convert the response to a `Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphUser` collection
    $facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();
    $current_user = $user;
    $current_user->facebook_id = $facebook_user['id'];
    $current_user->save();
} else {

$user = User::createOrUpdateGraphNode($facebook_user);

}

// Log the user into Laravel
Auth::login($user);

if (Auth::user()->terms && Auth::user()->active) {
    return redirect()->route('home');
}

$active = 1;
Auth::user()->update([
    'active' => $active,
]);

return redirect()->route('auth.signupdetails');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution, not it's not that elegant , but its not bad, it works. If any one can make this more elegant or if you see any concerns ,please drop a line. Here's what i did:

I replaced `$user = User::createOrUpdateGraphNode($facebook_user)`

with

```
if($user = User::where('email', $facebook_user['email'])->where('active', true)->first()) {
    // // Convert the response to a `Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphUser` collection
    $facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();
    $current_user = $user;
    $current_user->facebook_id = $facebook_user['id'];
    $current_user->save();
} // if facebook id exist in databse, just update
elseif ($user = User::where('facebook_id', $facebook_user['id'])->first()) {

    $facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();
    $current_user = $user;
    $current_user->facebook_id = $facebook_user['id'];
    $current_user->save();

} // if user facebook id and no email matching facebook's email is in the database, create new user
else {
    $facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();

     $user = User::create([
        'email' => $facebook_user['email'],
        'facebook_id' => $facebook_user['id'],
    ]);
}

// Log the user into Laravel
Auth::login($user);
```